# AWS-LAMBDA event parameters id does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, dynamodb-queries

I am practicing Dynamodb and its' queries. I am using serverless framework. I made post request where it takes global secondary index partition key is `Restaurant's name` and sort key is `uuid` .My Dynamodb table looks like this [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKe14.png). I want to make query my Global secondary index and it will take path parameter id and return me single restaurant's output.

I am testing my api by using postman. I made my global secondary index partition key same value which is `RESTAURANT` and passing my event.pathParameters.id value to `GSI1SK` and return me nothing. when I tested api-gate way it works, [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meTej.png). When i tested in my lambda function, it says pathparatmeter's id is `undefined`, [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSCYm.png). I don't get it how it works in api-gateway but not in lambda.

**This is serverless yml file where I declare single restaurant handler**

```
  getSingleRestaurant:
    handler: handlers/getSingleRestaurant.getSingleRestaurant
    events:
      - http:
          path: restaurant/{id}
          method: get
          cors: true
```

This is my get single Restaurant lambda function

```
'use strict'

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
module.exports.getSingleRestaurant = async event => {

  const restaurantId = decodeURIComponent(event.pathParameters.id);

  console.log(restaurantId); // i don't see any thing in cloud watch logs

  const params = {
    TableName: "table name",
    IndexName: "GSI1",
    KeyConditionExpression: 'GSI1PK = :hkey AND GSI1SK = :skey',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':hkey': 'RESTAURANT',
      ':skey': restaurantId
    },
    Limit: 1
  };

  try {
    let data = await dynamoDb.query(params).promise();

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify(data.Items[0])
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify(error),
    };
  }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

My `GSI1SK` id start with `R#`. when i tested my event parameter id after post request I got only `R` after # it does not take any value. So I modify my post request.

```js
  const params = {
    TableName: "table name",
    IndexName: "GSI1",
    KeyConditionExpression: 'GSI1PK = :hkey AND GSI1SK = :skey',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':hkey': 'RESTAURANT',
      ':skey': `R#${restaurantId}`
    },
    Limit: 1
  };
```